# Hover on child element and append scss on parent

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a scenario when on `hover` of child element, I want to append a style to the parent element. My code can be seen below, as well as [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/b8vsrzNVLfSbbbd7yKho?p=preview):

**html:**

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>hover</span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**scss:**

```
 span:hover{
   div{
     border:1px solid red;
   }
 }
```

On hovering over the child text, I need to set the border for the parent `div`. But it isn't happening that way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this [Question](https://jira.ascertia.com.pk/browse/SHE-5197)

Answer (score 1):

One cannot simply traverse up the DOM in CSS. You will need to use JavaScript or jQuery.

Here is an article explaining why: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors

TLDR, it's due to the way CSS is read by the browser, and if we were to traverse up the DOM, it would increase the performance hit by a factor of ten (at least!), because it would need to read every single node multiple times to see whether or not it fits the profile. Hence, it's simply not viable.

**Javascript way**

```js
document.getElementById("child").onmouseover = function() {
  this.parentNode.style.border = "1px solid red";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <span id="child">hover</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery way**

```js
$("#child").hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <span id="child">hover</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can't we do it using scss?

Comment: scss is only a css pre processor which renders code and gets compiled to css that is understood by the browser. So no it cannot be done in css neither in any of its pre processors.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("div span").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents('div').toggleClass("myClass");
  });
})
```

```css
.myClass{
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>hover</span>
</div>
```

Comment: abak
can't we do it using scss